# when is it a good idea to increase/decrease the number of nodes interactively on a hadoop mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, emr

I have an intuition that increasing/decreasing
number of nodes interactively on running job can speed up map-heavy
jobs, but won't help wth reduce heavy jobs, where most of work is done
by reduce.

There's an faq about this but it doesn't really explain very well

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/#cluster-18

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by Christopher Smith, who gave me permission to post here.

---

As always... "it depends". One thing you can pretty much always count
on: adding nodes later on is not going to help you as much as having
the nodes from the get go.

When you create a Hadoop job, it gets split up in to tasks. These
tasks are effectively "atoms of work". Hadoop lets you tweak the # of
mapper and # of reducer tasks during job creation, but once the job is
created, it is static. Tasks are assigned to "slots". Traditionally,
each node is configured to have a certain number of slots for map
tasks, and a certain number of slots for reduce tasks, but you can
tweak that. Some newer versions of Hadoop don't require you to
designate the slots as being for map or reduce tasks. Anyway, the
JobTracker periodically assigns tasks to slots. Because this is done
dynamically, new nodes coming online can speed up the processing of a
job by providing more slots to execute the tasks.

This sets the stage for understanding the reality of adding new nodes.
There's obviously an Amdahl's law issue where having more slots than
pending tasks accomplishes little (if you have speculative execution
enabled, it does help somewhat, as Hadoop will schedule the same task
to run on many different nodes, so that a slow node's tasks can be
completed by faster nodes if there are spare resources). So, if you
didn't define your job with many map or reduce tasks, adding more
nodes isn't going to help much. Of course, each task imposes some
overhead, so you don't want to go crazy high either. That's why I
suggest a guideline for task size should be "something which takes
~2-5 minutes to execute".

Of course, when you add nodes dynamically, they have one other
disadvantage: they don't have any data local. Obviously, if you are at
the start of a EMR pipeline, none of the nodes have data in them, so
doesn't matter, but if you have an EMR pipeline made of many jobs,
with earlier jobs persisting their results to HDFS, you get a huge
performance boost because the JobTracker will favour shaping and
assigning tasks so nodes have that lovely locality of data (this is a
core trick of the whole MapReduce design to maximize performance). On
the reducer side, data is coming from other map tasks, so dynamically
added nodes are really at no disadvantage as compared to other nodes.

So, in principle, dynamically adding new nodes is actually less likely
to help with IO bound map tasks that are reading from HDFS.

Except...

Hadoop has a variety of cheats under the covers to optimize
performance. Once is that it starts transmitting map output data to
the reducers *before* the map task completes/the reducer starts. This
obviously is a critical optimization for jobs where the mappers
generate a lot of data. You can tweak when Hadoop starts to kick off
the transfers. Anyway, this means that a newly spun up node might be
at a disadvantage, because the existing nodes might already have such
a huge data advantage. Obviously, the more output that the mappers
have transmitted, the larger the disadvantage.

That's how it all really works. In practice though, a lot of Hadoop
jobs have mappers processing tons of data in a CPU intensive fashion,
but outputting comparatively little data to the reducers (or they
might send a lot of data to the reducers, but the reducers are still
very simple, so not CPU bound at all). Often jobs will have few
(sometimes even 0) reducer tasks, so even extra nodes could help, if
you already have a reduce slot available for every outstanding reduce
task, new nodes can't help. New nodes also disproportionately help out
with CPU bound work, for obvious reasons, so because that *tends* to
be map tasks more than reduce tasks, that's where people typically see
the win. If your mappers are I/O bound and pulling data from the
network, adding new nodes obviously increases the aggregate bandwidth
of the cluster, so it helps there, but if your map tasks are I/O bound
reading HDFS, the best thing is to have more initial nodes, with data
already spread over HDFS. It's not unusual to see reducers get I/O
bound because of poorly structured jobs, in which case adding more
nodes can help a lot, because it splits up the bandwidth again.

There's a caveat there too of course: with a really small cluster,
reducers get to read a lot of their data from the mappers running on
the local node, and adding more nodes shifts more of the data to being
pulled over the much slower network. You can also have cases where
reducers spend most of their time just multiplexing data processing
from all the mappers sending them data (although that is tunable as
well).

If you are asking questions like this, I'd highly recommend profiling
your job using something like Amazon's offering of KarmaSphere. It
will give you a better picture of where your bottlenecks are and what
are your best strategies for improving performance.